# Smart Lock Hint Picker crashing

Tags: google-play-services, google-smartlockpasswords

After implementing the Smart Lock hint picker as described here:
https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/retrieve-hints

I get the following crash from Google Play services:

```
03-08 16:31:55.732 6964-6964/? W/Bundle: Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
                                         java.lang.ClassCastException: byte[] cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable
                                             at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:1212)
                                             at android.content.Intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.java:5007)
                                             at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.credentials.ui.CredentialPickerChimeraActivity.onCreate(:com.google.android.gms:2119)
                                             at com.google.android.chimera.Activity.publicOnCreate(:com.google.android.gms:303)
                                             at com.google.android.chimera.container.ActivityProxy.onCreate(:com.google.android.gms:305)
                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5312)
                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2552)
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2653)
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-08 16:31:55.732 6964-6964/? W/Bundle: Key com.google.android.gms.credentials.HintRequest expected Parcelable but value was a [B.  The default value <null> was returned.
03-08 16:31:55.732 6964-6964/? W/Bundle: Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
                                         java.lang.ClassCastException: byte[] cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable
                                             at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:1212)
                                             at android.content.Intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.java:5007)
                                             at egv.b(:com.google.android.gms:115)
                                             at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.credentials.ui.CredentialPickerChimeraActivity.onCreate(:com.google.android.gms:174)
                                             at com.google.android.chimera.Activity.publicOnCreate(:com.google.android.gms:303)
                                             at com.google.android.chimera.container.ActivityProxy.onCreate(:com.google.android.gms:305)
                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5312)
                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2552)
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2653)
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-08 16:31:55.732 6964-6964/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41642e18)
03-08 16:31:55.822 6964-6964/? I/DeviceDoctorDatabaseHelper: Cleaning stale data from database!
03-08 16:31:55.862 6964-6964/? W/DeviceDoctorHandler: Crash Hash: 0b120f68bbc35a8214ee03ee607628abc1c08205
03-08 16:31:55.872 1060-1193/? E/ActivityManager: App crashed! Process: com.google.android.gms.ui
03-08 16:31:55.872 6964-6964/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.google.android.gms.ui, PID: 6964
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.credentials.ui.CredentialPickerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2596)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2653)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                     at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.credentials.ui.CredentialPickerChimeraActivity.onCreate(:com.google.android.gms:3148)
                                                     at com.google.android.chimera.Activity.publicOnCreate(:com.google.android.gms:303)
                                                     at com.google.android.chimera.container.ActivityProxy.onCreate(:com.google.android.gms:305)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5312)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2552)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2653) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674) 
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This happens on the HTC One Mini 2 and Samsung Galaxy SII phones.

So the question is, will Google fix that?

Comment: playServicesVersion = '10.2.0', 

Google Play Services on device is 10.0.84

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by factory resetting the HTC One Mini 2 and updating Google Play services to 10.2.98 on the device.